# How to find the Expected height of a randomly built binary tree

Tags: probability, algorithms, computer-science, expected-value, algorithmic-randomness

I would like to find out the Expected height of a binary tree where the insertions are based on a random function. I.e. for each node I visit, there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of choosing right or left. I know that the following property holds for height $h$, but it's difficult to add the probability:$$h_{tree}= 1+max(h_{left}, h_{right})$$I think that this version/random tree differs from the random (search) tree mentioned in CLRS chapter 12.4, where you pick a random element from a sorted list $\{1,\dots, n\}$ and insert based on whether the visited node is greater or less than the inserted element. Because, here we choose each path on each visited node to be random.

Note: the binary tree has all its elements at the leafs and internal nodes are only used for routing.

```
//pseudocode
insert(i, tree):
    if at leaf v:
        split(); //Create a parent u and set its children to be the leaf v and element i.
    else:
        int left = random()
        int right = random()
        if (left > right):
            insert(i, left-subtree):
        else:
            insert(i, right-subtree)
```

See this figure (also in the link on CS stackexhange - https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/136582/how-to-find-the-expected-height-of-a-randomly-built-binary-tree)

[image]

Comment: Hi. I am referring to chapter 12.4

Comment: We needs answer peeps...

Comment: @MadHatter I don't understand the question. Are you building the binary tree randomly? Or travelling randomly along a given one? Can you please fully state the problem precisely? Thanks.

Comment: @MadHatter This doesn't sound like a hard combinatorics question, but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how you're building your tree, or what the random process here even is...

Comment: Wait, are you itteratively building the tree node by node? If so, are you looking for the expected height of the tree after $n$ nodes have been placed?

Comment: @C-RAM Just trying to learn as much as possible about this. An answer would benefit all of us.

Comment: @MadHatter I hope it didn't sound like I was trying to dismiss the question. I wasn't. I want to try to answer it, but I'm really confused about what the precise problem statement is (and it looks like I'm not the only one). The poster might want to try to write a clearer explanation of things, and maybe even run through an example if you want someone to give an answer.

Comment: @C-RAM Take a shot, please--fool in the rough playing against type (no natural aptitude in the grey matter between my ears--been in over my head since I first dove into Computer Science)--it will help me and other similar algorithmic sorcerers in the rough. May the Source serve you well.

Comment: @C-RAM Pick an iteration of the above problem that lets you provide an answer, for the sake of clarity. Also, I detect genuine sincerity in your words; success and prosperity upon you and all you do. Thank you for not being one of the many higher ups who derive joy from condescension, pettiness, and overall invalidating and discouraging we passionate fools in the rough. Algorithmic naïveté. Prism of creativity.

Comment: When you split, do you put the old one to the left and the new one to the right, or vice versa, maybe with 0.5 probability? Or it doesn't matter? (You don't distinguish between those two cases [i.e. treat as same tree]?)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that I have understood the question correctly, let $H_n$ be a random variable which equals the height of the tree with $n\ge 1$ elements.  Then $H_1=0$, $H_2=1$, $H_3=2$ and, more generally, for all integers $m\ge 0$,
$$
H_{m+2}=_d1+\max(H_{k+1}, J_{m-k+1}), \qquad \hbox{where}\ \ \  k \sim {\rm Binomial}(m, \frac 1 2),
$$
$$
\hbox{$J_{m-k+1}=_d H_{m-k+1},\ \ $ and $H_{k+1}$ and $J_{m-k+1}$ are independent conditioned on $k$. $\ $ (*)}
$$
This is because, after adding the first two elements, which must go on the left and right sides of the root, each of the next $m$ elements added will each go, independently, on either the left or right sides of the root, with probability $\frac 1 2$ for each case.  This gives two subtrees with $k+1$ and $m-k+1$ elements, where $k$ is the number of the $m$ elements which went left.  Observe that we always have $H_n\le n-1$.

For integers $i\ge 0$, let $p_{ni}$ be the probability that $H_n$ is $i$ or less.  Then $H_1=0$ together with (*) immediately gives the recurrence
$$
p_{ni}=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 1,&\ \ &\hbox{if $n=1$,}\\
0,&\ \ &\hbox{if $n>1$ and $i=0$,}\\
2^{-(n-2)} \sum_{0\le k\le n-2} \binom{n-2}{k} p_{(k+1)(i-1)} p_{(n-k-1)(i-1)},&\ \ &\hbox{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right\}\ \ (!)
$$
This can be used to compute the expected value of $H_n$ by using
$$
{\Bbb E}H_n=\sum_{i\ge 0} {\Bbb P}(H_n>i) = \sum_{i\ge 0} (1 - p_{ni}).\qquad(@)
$$
What is the approximate value of ${\Bbb E} H_n$ for large $n$?  I will prove that
$$
{\Bbb E} H_{n+1}=\log_2 n + O((\log n)^{2/3}),\qquad n\ge 1,
$$
although the error term could surely be improved.

It's clear that $H_{n+1}\ge \log_2 (n+1)\ge \log_2 n$ always.
To prove an upper bound on $H_{n+1}$, I will prove by induction on $i$ that
$$
p_{(n+1)i}\ge 1-e^{-A (i-B)} n^c, \qquad 
\hbox{for all integers $n\ge 0$, $i\ge 0$},\ \ (+)
$$
where $c:=A(1+\epsilon)/\log 2$,
for appropriately chosen $0<\epsilon\le 1$, $A>0$ and $B>0$.  If $n=0$, (+) is clear as the left-hand side is 1.  Otherwise let $n=m+1$, $m\ge 0$.  If $i=0$, (+) is true since $-A(i-B)=AB\ge 0$, so the right-hand side of (+) is nonpositive; if $m=0$
and $i>0$, (+) is true since the left-hand side is 1.
Otherwise, by (*) or (!),
$$
p_{(m+2)i}={\Bbb E}(p_{(k+1)(i-1)}p_{(m-k+1)(i-1)})
$$
where the expectation value is taken over the binomially distributed $k$, so by the induction
hypothesis
\begin{eqnarray*}
p_{(m+2)i}&\ge& {\Bbb E}[\max(1-e^{-A ((i-1)-B)} k^c, 0)\\
&&\ \ \ \ \max(1-e^{-A ((i-1)-B)} (m-k)^c, 0)]\\
&\ge& 1-e^{-A(i-1-B)} {\Bbb E}[k^c+(m-k)^c]\\
&=& 1-2 e^{-A(i-1-B)} {\Bbb E}(k^c).
\end{eqnarray*}
Then, by [Corollary 1 here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.17027),
$$
{\Bbb E}(k^c)\le (\frac m 2)^c e^{c^2/m},
$$
so
$$
p_{(m+2)i} \ge 1-2 e^{-A(i-1-B)} (\frac m 2)^c e^{c^2/m},
$$
which will complete the induction if
$$
2 e^A 2^{-c} e^{c^2/m} \le (1+\frac 1 m)^c,
$$
or certainly if
$$
2 e^{-A \epsilon} e^{c^2/m} \le 1.
$$
We can satisfy this by setting $A:=\epsilon^{-1}$ as long as
$$
m\ge m_0:=\frac {c^2}{1 - \log 2} = \frac 1 {1 -\log 2} (\frac {1 + \epsilon^{-1}}{\log 2})^2.
$$
In order to complete the induction for $m<m_0$, we set $B:=m_0+1$;
then if $m<m_0$, $H_{m+2}\le m+1< m_0+1=B$, so if $i\ge B$, $p_{(m+2)i}=1$,
automatically satisfying (+); if $i<B$, $-A(i-B)>0$, so the right-hand side
of (+) is nonpositive.  This completes the proof of (+).

Now from (@) and (+),
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\Bbb E}H_{n+1}&=& \sum_{i\ge 0} (1 - p_{(n+1)i})\\
&\le& I_0 + \sum_{i\ge I_0} e^{-A(i-B)} n^c,
\end{eqnarray*}
where $I_0:=\lceil m_0+(1+\epsilon)\log_2 n + 2\rceil$; then
$$
e^{-A(I_0-B)} n^c \le e^{-1/\epsilon}
$$
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\Bbb E}H_{n+1}&\le& I_0 + e^{-1/\epsilon} + e^{-2/\epsilon} + \cdots\\
&\le& I_0 + \epsilon \\
&\le& \frac 1 {1 -\log 2} (\frac {1 + \epsilon^{-1}}{\log 2})^2+(1+\epsilon)\log_2 n + 3 + \epsilon\\
&\le& K \epsilon^{-2} + (1 + \epsilon) \log_2 n,
\end{eqnarray*}
for some constant $K>0$.  Setting $\epsilon:=(\log (n+2))^{-1/3}$ now gives the desired bound on ${\Bbb E}H_{n+1}$.

Comment: Sorry, why $H_1=0, H_2=1, H_3=2$? If $H_n$ is "the height of the tree with $n\ge 1$ elements", it should be $H_1=1, H_2=1$ or $2$, $H_3=2$ or $3$. Please explain.

Comment: This seems to be because you assume "the first two elements [which] must go on the left and right sides of the root". I don't see that in the OP post.

Comment: The first element goes at the root, so you get a tree with one root node and no edges.  I'm taking this to have height 0.  If you add another element, according to the pseudocode above, `split()` is called once and you get a tree with one root node and two children, which are the two elements (the order of the children doesn't matter.)  I take this to have height 1.

Comment: If you add a third element, you descend either to the left or to the right and call `split()` again, replacing one of the leaf nodes with a three-node tree with a new parent node whose children are the new element and the old element; again, the order of the children doesn't matter.  The resultant tree will look like the picture above in the question or its mirror image, except that the elements may be permuted.  This tree has height 2.

Comment: OK, I assumed the root position was already filled at beginning; and I assumed the elements would stay in place. Re-reading the OP question (which is not clear) you are probably right. Thanks.